# Turning JSON list into POJO

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, pojo

Here's the JSON:

```
{  
   "Want":{  
      "ABCD-1234-ABCD-1234-ABCD-125A":3,
      "ABCD-1234-ABCD-1234-ABCD-129B":5,
      "ABCD-1234-ABCD-1234-ABCD-123C":10
   },
   "EndPoint":"https://example.com/gossip/asff3"
}
```

And my current POJO:

```
public class WantMessage {

@JsonProperty("Want")
    Map<String, String> wantmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
@JsonProperty("EndPoint")
    public String EndPoint;
}
```

I get the "Endpoint" String in ok but am missing the data in the "Want" section. How would you pull in the want list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wantmap` has keys and values of type `String`. The map in json has `int` values. Try putting the numbers in double quotes, and see if it works.